# Graph plotting C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, graph, serial-port

I am working on an interface in C#, which reads data from the serial port and displays it on a graph. I wrote the following code, but the graph doesn't display anything. What is wrong? I don't know exactly what should I modify.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public long rt = 0;
        string dataReceived = string.Empty;
        private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);

     //  public string kp, kd, ki;
       public int distanta;
       public string potentiometru;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
            this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 55;
        }

        private void Connect_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                Connect_button.Enabled = false;
            }
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;// Convert.ToUInt16(comboBox1.Text);
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBox3.Text;
            serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort1.StopBits = (System.IO.Ports.StopBits)2;
            timer1.Start();
            serialPort1.Open();

        }

        private void Sent_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //  kp = Convert.ToString(Kp_textbox.Text);
            //kd = Convert.ToString(Kd_textbox.Text);
            //ki = Convert.ToString(Ki_textbox.Text);
            //serialPort1.Write(kp);
            //serialPort1.Write(ki);
            //serialPort1.Write(kd);

            //string transmit = "$kp$" + kp + "$kd$" + kd + "$ki$" + ki;
               // $kp$0.25

        }


       private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string x = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(DataReceived), new object[] { x });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

       private void DataReceived(string data)
       {
          dataReceived = data.Trim();
          if (rt < 2)
              return;
           if (dataReceived.Contains("."))
           {
              senzor_textbox.Text = dataReceived;
              this.chart1.Series["Distance"].Points.AddXY(0, dataReceived);
           }
           else
           {
               potentiometru_textbox.Text = dataReceived;
               this.chart1.Series["SetPoint"].Points.AddXY(0, dataReceived);
           }
           rt = 0;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rt++;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(serialPort1.IsOpen)
                serialPort1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this.chart1.Series["Distance"].Points.AddXY(0, dataReceived); you are adding x-axis value always as 'zero'.

Comment: And how should I correct it, more exactly ?

Comment: Either use AddY() or set yourSeries.IsXValueIndexed = true;